# Apache Spark java home setting

Tags: java, apache-spark, ssh

I have 9 nodes to run `Apache Spark`, and all nodes have same username (say `Jack`). 6 nodes of them (including `master`) have also password (say `pwd1`), while the remaining 3 nodes have another password (say `pwd2`). And I have set the `ssh`.

I set the `JAVA_HOME` in the `.bashrc` in `Jack`'s home, but when I execute

```
./sbin/start-all.sh
```

in `Apache Spark`, the **3 nodes whose password is pwd2** raise error:

> JAVA_HOME is not set

While the remaining 6 nodes whose password is pwd1 are launched successfully.

My first question is: **must the password be same for a `Spark` cluster?** I know that same username is necessary.

By the way, if we set the `JAVA_HOME` in `spark-env.sh` directly, all nodes are launched successfully.

My second question is: for the 3 nodes whose password is pwd2, why `JAVA_HOME` in `.bashrc` does not work, while `JAVA_HOME` in `spark-env.sh` works?

The `Java` version is `jdk1.8.0_161`, and the `Spark` version is `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7`.

Comment: It seems that setting `JAVA_HOME` in `spark-env.sh` is a good practice. But I want to know the possibility that setting it in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Why are you mentioning the passwords? Is it because you have not set up password-less ssh?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele My ssh is password-less. It seems strange to me because only these nodes whose password is `pwd2` report `JAVA_HOME  not set`

Comment: While it's possible that there be a small bug somewhere, it's rather very likely that this is an installation affair. With ssh keys in use, password differences are far from being able to influence this scenario. Maybe... just maybe, something is different on the other machines, especially if your installation was done manually, the second set of servers may be having a different environment variable map in the end. But this needs to be checked on each machine...

Comment: you mentioned `.bashrc`. But do you have a `.bash_profile` on these hosts, since this is the file which is entry point in the bash shell, that may in turn be sourcing `.bashrc`